# How to configure the Jenkins E-mail Notification to use Roundcube email server

Tags: jenkins, smtp, jakarta-mail, email-notifications, roundcube

I want to configure my Jenkins' E-mail Notification system. But I am getting error while sending test email to my Roundcube Webmail.

This is my settings :

[image: E-mail Notification]

I get the following error when running test connection :

[image: Error stacktrace]

I use Roundcube as SMTP mail server. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've configured your SMTP port to use the IMAP port.  That's not going to work.  You need to determine which SMTP port your mail server uses, and whether or not it requires SSL.